# Python - How to center align text while using typewriter effect

Tags: python

First post here so i apologize for any wrong formatting etc.

I'm fresh to coding and i'm making a text based adventure using Python. It works fine but I want to center align all my text. I checked online and found the center(width) function. However, i'm using a function that types the string out with a typewriter effect and if i add deliberate spaces before the text in my string, even the blank spaces get a typewriter effect which I don't want.

I want my text to start printing in the center of my window. Is there a way to do this with a string that already has a function applied on it? code below :

---

```
import sys
import time

def typewriter(message):

    for char in message:
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.04)

def character_info():
    message = "Before we start, please enter your name below :\n"
    typewriter(message)
    input("\n>>> ")


character_info()
```

---

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing that  - but since you roled out your own `typewriter` code, one of the easier is just to ignore leading white-space:

```py
import sys
import time

def typewriter(message):
    started = False
    for char in message:
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        if char != " ":
            started = True
        if started:
            time.sleep(0.04)
```

To have the code return immediately after the last char is printed,
one easy thing is to strip all whitespace on the right-side of the string, before looping over the characters:

```py
import sys
import time

def typewriter(message):
    message = message.rstrip()
    started = False
    for char in message:
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        if char != " ":
            started = True
        if started:
            time.sleep(0.04)
```